# ¿Cómo hago para que el archivo que transformé de excel a csv pueda ser visto en JupyterLab usando Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv, jupyter

En mi primera prueba al usar Jupyterlab para programar en Python, adjunté un archivo en excel lo volví archivo en CSV, le hice clic en editar al archivo en formato CSV para rectificar que lo estuviera. Luego de ello lo adjunté directamente a Jupyter Labs, desafortunadamente al quererlo abrir l hacer clic en éste mediante el siguiente código **(ya he intentado como otros archivos transformados desde excel a csv y ocurre lo mismo)**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('PELICULA.CSV')

df.head()
```

**Al compilarlo, desafortunadamente me sale el siguiente error**:

```
-------------------------------------------------
Name Error   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1c42a152c7cf> in <module>
------> 1 df.head()

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

*Presento pantallazo de lo que me sale como evidencia:*

[image: <code>introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí</code>]

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo. Estás ejecutando solo la tercera celda sin ejecutar las primeras dos, por lo que no se ha creado la variable.

Esto lo puedes ver en los corchetes que te indican el orden de ejecución con el número que tienen dentro, y si no tienen número es que no se ejecutó la celda.

En tu caso debería verse como:

```
[1] import pandas
[2] df = pd.read_csv('PELICULA.CSV')
[3] df.head()
```

No necesitas poner todo el path al archivo si es que está en el mismo directorio

Answer (score -1):

Para la lectura del archivo *.csv* te recomiendo que lo hagas con una ruta absoluta y no relativa tal cual como lo siguiente

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('C:\\')/'Users'/'username'/'folder'/'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

con esto te aseguras de que funcione correctamente.

Puedes leer el codigo original [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543777/how-to-read-local-csv-files-in-jupyterlab)